# Best M.2 SSD format settings for shared Linux/Windows drive

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, m.2

I have a 1TB M.2 SSD in my PC that I want to format to use as my Linux drive for a dual-boot Linux setup.  When I go to format the disk, I can allocate in units of 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 and so on bytes.  The default is 4096 bytes.

Should I prefer a particular byte size?

Note: NTFS is the only file system type showing in the Windows 10 Format dialog box, so I hope that's not an issue for Ubuntu as well.